# Flyway migrations: [WARNING] Unable to restore connection to having no default schema

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I'm encountering a warning when running my migrations and I don't understand what the message means.

The message is: [WARNING] Unable to restore connection to having no default schema: Access denied for user ''@'%' to database ''

My migrations appear to be running correctly, so I know my DB connection is ok.

What is the significance of "having no default schema" in this message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some googling around this issue and here's what I have found: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/793

Apparently, at a certain point of time, there is a DB connection with no schema selected, which causes that warning to be thrown.

As a solution, you could make sure to always have the default schema name in your JDBC connection string.